# How would a date be written on a German manuscript circa 1445?

Tags: middle-ages, germany

How would a date be written on a German manuscript circa 1445? Would it be written in Roman numerals, or written out in regular numbers?

Answer (score 3):

If the manuscript was created in a religious house, then the manuscript would probably be written in Latin, and dates would probably be written in Roman numerals. This example shows the [record of the heresy trial of Johann von Wesel](http://dla.library.upenn.edu/dla/medren/pageturn.html?id=MEDREN_1580406&fq=century_facet%3A%2215th%20century%22%20AND%20geography_facet%3A%22Germany%22&currentpage=7&rotation=0&size=0) in 1479. Note that the date at the top of folio 1 recto was truncated when the manuscript was bound.

There seem to be few examples of 15th-century German manuscripts available online. There are some nice examples of 15th-century German manuscripts in the [collection of the Bodleian library](http://www.bodley.ox.ac.uk/dept/scwmss/wmss/medieval/mss/misc/15th-germ.htm), although none of the online examples appear to show dates.

---

Even when the text was written in German, it is likely that dates would be written in Roman Numerals as well as "Arabic" numerals, as illustrated by the [Mckell Medical Almanack](https://cdn.globalauctionplatform.com/6599b8a4-8ad2-4abe-87c8-a4b500e987d3/3ca909d4-5573-49b2-c313-df0990164833/original.jpg), which is [dated](https://www.the-saleroom.com/en-gb/auction-catalogues/bloomsbury-auctions/catalogue-id-blooms10060/lot-64a078d5-6115-4178-8894-a4b500ea121d) c. 1445.

Comment: Nice pictures, but where are the dates?

Comment: Yes, but the question was what sort of numerals they used, not which language.

Comment: @fdb As I said, if the language a manuscript was written in was was Latin, then any dates would normally be in Roman numerals.

Comment: I am afraid you are totally wrong. The Arabic/Indian numerals are used in Latin manuscripts at the latest from the 12th century onwards.

Comment: @fdb Yes. But rarely this early in manuscripts created in religious houses in Germany. Arabic numerals were initially brought back to France & Italy by Crusaders returning from the Holy Land, Many German crusades were [directed elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crusade_of_1197). See Guide to Western Historical Scripts from Antiquity to 1600 by Michelle P. Brown for more info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65229/discussion-between-sempaiscuba-and-fdb).